# Software as Service(SaaS) Configuration management/architecture pattern for .Net

Tags: .net, configuration, multi-tenant, saas

We are planning to modify our single tenant application to multi tenant support and the same time we should allow customer to configure the application, like database (customer can choose their own database), logging (file logging, database logging), etc.

Difficulty is how can we store and secure configurations from other customer?

Is there any article/suggestion for Configuration management in SaaS applications?

Answer (score 0):

There are may options available for this query of yours

1. In order to store the database partitions for customer, you could take a look at the Azure DB Shard Management feature
2. Regarding the custom metadata per customer, its easy to be stored along with a tenant identifier per row. This helps us to easily get the customization per tenant.

Example

```
tenantid           setting             value    
tenant1            logo                company1.png
tenant2            passwordfailcount   5
```

For logging, the logs can be stored in the tenant specific database if you wish to opt for complete isolation, however, to start with you can still have the log data in a single database with all the data per table distinguished with tenantid column.

HTH